# Is there a way to send an email when a build in queue is cancelled?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to find a way to send an email when a queued build is cancelled, and have that email contain the name of the user that cancelled the build. Am I missing a setting somewhere or is there a plugin I need?

Answer (score 0):

We use [Email Extension](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/) plugin.
After installation you will have new step option in **Post-build Actions** of a job named **Editable Email Notification**. In the **Advanced settings** of this step you can add trigger **Aborted**.

Comment: That's the one I'm using but I cant seem to find a way to include the user who cancelled the build in the message.